# Control Version System - update children when updating their parent?

Tags: version-control

I have big problem with my control version system.
In DB I have 2 tables: `FolderChanges` and `FileChanges`. The new record is inserted when I commit a change.

*For example:*

- `File1 has id=1 and orginalid=1` (points to the first version of file)
- I change it and insert `File2 id=2 orginalid=1`.

But the problem is with folders. Files and folders have a FolderId (which points to their parents).

So if I change a folder I have to change its child.

So my question is this:

Should I insert a new record in the `FileChanges` table with the same data and only `FolderId` changed or should I add a column in `FileChanges` (for example: `ChangeDate`) and when parents are updated (new file in `FolderChanges`) change the `FolderId` pointer to the newest version of the parent and modify ChangeDate?

I hope I explained that well enough.
Thanks!

Comment: To pull an Indiana Jones here, why don't you just use Git?

Comment: Its system for our company's projects. It has to be done as module of our application.

Comment: Sounds like an CMS. Ask yourself:; what is important for the file if its folder changes. You could keep the folderid on file / parentfolderid on folder to the originalid of its folder/parentfolder. That way you do not have to change anything on the file if its folder changes - it simple uses the "newest" version of its folder/parentfolder. If a folder gets deleted though, you need to mark all contained files als deleted as well which might merit a new file version with a (was deleted) flag&date. The company I work for deals in CMS aswell ;) Disclaimer: I am not DB-Serverside.